# How can I migrate / export all my fields from Amazon ECS to a different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, export, amazon-ecs

I'm currently working on a project that was built using a personal Amazon ECS. However, now that the client wants to take it into production, they want to migrate it to an account they own.

I was wondering if there is any way to export the field configuration and even the data to json or xml.

By searching the Amazon documentation, I see they have tools to import json in, but there's no information regarding export.

I was able to find this question [How do I migrate an Amazon EC2 Instance to a different account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299085/how-do-i-migrate-an-amazon-ec2-instance-to-a-different-account) here, which seems to be what I want to do, but there's no real answer to it.

So, a bit of wishful thinking here: did this change in the meantime? Does Amazon actually have a way to export ECS field configuration and data to a format that can then be important to a new account?

Comment: Not really an answer to the problem, but I just created a small java application using the Amazon API that migrates all the indexes from one account to another. I'll tidy it up and share it on github when I have some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Amazon doesn't provide any tool to migrate between accounts, so I created one. 
You can get it here: https://github.com/bcatarino/migrateECS.
Feel free to use it or improve it at your will.